# Выполнить M операций вычисления количества нулевых элементов на отрезке

Tags: c++, алгоритм

> Задан числовой массив A [1..N]. Необходимо выполнить M операций
>   вычисления количества нулевых элементов на отрезке [L, R].
>
> **Входные данные**
>
> Первая строка входного файла `INPUT.TXT` содержит число N – размер
>   массива (N ≤ 10<sup>5</sup>). Во второй строке записаны N чисел –
>   элементы массива, целые числа от 0 до 10<sup>5</sup>. Третья строка
>   содержит натуральное число M – количество запросов (M ≤ 30 000).
>   Следующие M строк содержат пары чисел L и R (1 ≤ L ≤ R ≤ N),
>   описывающие отрезки.
>
> **Выходные данные**
>
> В выходной файл `OUTPUT.TXT` для каждого запроса выведите через пробел
>   количество нулевых элементов.

Я написал структуру данных, но в моем коде есть подвох. Помогите найти мою ошибку или написать правильный код.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

typedef long long ll;
typedef unsigned long long ull;
typedef long double ld;

const ll N = 1e5 + 5;
const ll MAX = 2e5 + 123;
const ll MOD = 1e9 + 7;

using namespace std;

ll n, m, a[ N ];
vector< ll > v;

int main()
{
    scanf( "%I64d", &n );
    ll len = ceil( sqrt( n ) );
    vector< ll > b( n );
    for( ll i = 0; i < n; i ++ )
    { 
        scanf( "%I64d", &a[ i ] );
        b[ i ] = 0;
    }
    for( ll i = 0; i < n; i ++ )
    {
        b[ i / len ] += a[ i ] == 0;
    }
    scanf( "%I64d", &m );
    while( m -- )
    {
        ll l, r, sum = 0;
        scanf( "%I64d%I64d", &l, &r );
        ll c_l = l / len, c_r = r / len;
        if( c_l == c_r )
        {
            for( ll i = l; i <= r; i ++ ) 
                if( a[ i ] == 0 ) 
                    sum ++;
        }
        else 
        {
            for (int i=l, end=(c_l+1)*len-1; i<=end; ++i)
                if( !a[ i ] )
                    sum ++;
            for (int i=c_l+1; i<=c_r-1; ++i)
                sum += b[i];
            for (int i=c_r*len; i<=r; ++i)
                if( !a[ i ] )
                    sum ++;
        }
        v.push_back( sum );
    }
    for( ll i = 0; i < v.size(); i ++ ) 
        cout << v[ i ] << ' ';
}
```

Comment: Отвечающим бы очень помогло описание того что программа должна делать и в чем конкретно заключается ошибка.

Comment: @trollingchar я сам не знаю в чем проблема так как я еще учусь в школе и решаю только задачи и в сайте который я решаю задачи не показывает непройденные тесты

Comment: На этом сайте вам наверняка дали четкие условия, ограничения на входные и выходные данные, примеры этих данных. Нас же вы всего этого лишаете, вместо этого показываете свой нечитаемый и нерабочий код.

Comment: Подсказка: наверняка тесты устроены так, что вычисление полной суммы для каждой пары `[L, R]` займет очень много времени. Придумайте способ чтобы обрабатывать каждую такую пару за минимум действий, без вложенного цикла. Почитайте про динамическое программирование.

Comment: Уже второй раз встречаю и правлю подобный код. Вчера в одном из вопросов был очень похожий. Это взято из какого-то учебника, руководства или примера?

Comment: @V-Mor взято [отсюда](https://acmp.ru/asp/do/index.asp?main=task&id_course=2&id_section=20&id_topic=44&id_problem=290) скорее всего

Comment: @extrn да взято там

Comment: @extrn тут я должен решать эту задачу с помощю sqrt декомпозиция но все же мой код не проходит тесты но с временем все в порядке

Comment: @extrn Я имею в виду сам код, а не задачу.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для этой задачи достаточно сделать массив, в котором записаны количества нулевых элементов по K-ю ячейку включительно.

```
0  1  2  3  4  5  6   индекс    
.  3  0  2  1  0  5   входной массив
0  0  1  1  1  2  2   накопленная сумма количества нулей
```

Тогда ответ на запрос - это просто разность `B[R]-B[L-1]`

```
С(2,5) = B[5] - B[1] = 2 - 0 = 2
```